# How to convert string into string array

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

If i have string like that:

```
string s = "xzy...";
```

how to convert it to array like that:

```
string[] ss = {"x", "z", "y", ...}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for `ToCharArray()`.

This returns an array of `char`s.
If you really need an array of `string`s, you can write

```
Array.ConvertAll(s.ToCharArray(), c => c.ToString())
```

Comment: I knew that there is method `s.ToCharArray()` but didn't know how to convert it to string array just using just one line of code.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to convert it to an array of characters you can use

```
s.ToCharArray();
```

But note that it already implements `IEnumerable<char>` and has an indexer by position. If you really need strings

```
s.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray()
```